# c# socket: get server when client connects

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

i have a Server socket using an async functions to allow a client socket to connect. And when i call Socket.EndAccept()  it returns a copy of the client Socket,

i'd like some way for the client socket connecting to get a copy of the Server socket

is this possible?

EDIT: question was rather forumlated weird, sorry, found a solution to the problem though.

The problem was that when i tried to send reply back to the client i used the server socket instead of the socket returned from `Socket.endAccept()`

Thank you

Comment: The term client/server is a bit misleading when you are talking about TCP sockets, client is the side which initiates the communication, server is the receiving part - after the start both sides, can send and receive simultaniously, but both parts are two seperate entities.

Comment: @weismat ok, but what i have programmed is a async `OnDataReceived` function, but it only works on server side now, so if data is received from client, the server can't send an answer back, i'll add code to my question

Comment: You need to include more code as there is not enough to get a clear picture of what you are doing. can you add the code for `sendData`, `WaitForData` and `secondPartSocket`

Comment: Got it working, What i did wrong is that on Serverside i didn't use the send() function of the socket returned from `socket.EndAccept()` but the server socket itself.

Answer (score 1):

ehh? You just used it when calling `Socket.EndAccept()`?

`Socket` is the server socket.

Comment: yes, this way the serverside gets a handle to the remote client, but i'd like to get a handle of the server socket on the clientside

Comment: That's not possible. Why do you think that you need it?